# multithreading in wpf/wcf project

Tags: wpf, multithreading, wcf

When an interviewer asked me: what kind of multithreading have you done in wpf/wcf project? I told him that I used backgroundworker to do a long-running task then used dispatcher begininvoke when I needed to update the UI thread. Obviously he wasn't satisfied with my answer. I guess he was expecting more knowledge of the candidate from this question? Can someone give a list of items that should be covered in the multithreading in wpf/wcf?

Comment: backgroundworker has some more features you (maybe) missed: you call the backgroundworker from the ui thread - the DoWork method then runs on a background thread, and the callback is again back on the ui-thread - so you dont need the dispatcher at all - and i think this is the wrong place for such an question...

Answer (score 1):

WPF/WCF has nothing to do threads.

You can create threads in any kind of application from web to windows(winforms/wpf) to console.

Wonderful discussions :

[about interviewer's perspective on MultiThreading](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49936/c-multithreading-interview-questions-for-a-senior-developer-designer-position)

[about important multithreading concepts in java](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-important-multithreading-concepts-in-Java) (concepts applies to c# too)

There are numerous good reading material on web. I recommend following :

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture))

[MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx)

[Free E-Book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

[High Recommended CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14746/Multithreading-Tutorial)

Not related to multi-threading, but a good link : 
[Programmer's competency matrix](http://sijinjoseph.com/programmer-competency-matrix/)